# Could not load file or assembly (BadImageFormatException and FileNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly, revit-api

I have two class libraries `core` and `plugins` and a WPF application that uses these two libraries. In `core` I dynamically load the `plugins` as follows:

```
try
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("plugins.dll");
        }
```

After I load the `plugins.dll` I get the types in the `plugins` that has implemented `Node` abstract class from `core` library, that is a class defined in the `core`. This is the scenario that I used to develop and extensible application.
Somewhere in my `core` library I need to traverse all fields of `Node` classes loaded from `plugins`. It works nice for all fields like `int`, `double` and other custom classes that are defined inside `plugins` library.

```
theList = assembly.GetTypes().ToList().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Node)).ToList();
var fieldInfos = theList[0].GetType().GetRuntimeFields();
foreach (var item in fieldInfos)
        {
            Type type = item.FieldType; 
            // Here I get exception for fields like XYZ that defined in
            // Revit API though for fields like Int and double it works charm
        }
```

But the problem is that in `plugins` project, I also use Revit API, and when the above loop reaches to a field that comes from `RevitAPI.dll` I get the following exception (I tried target platform Any and x86):

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'RevitAPI, 
Version=2015.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its 
dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

When I change the target platform in build section of all 3 projects to x64 I get this exception, instead:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'RevitAPI.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: are you loading the DLL on Revit on loadring on the WPF app (.exe)?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves In my WPF application I use the `core` library which loads the `plugins.dll`, dynamically using `Assembly.LoadFile()` . and `plugins.dll` itself references the `RevitAPI.dll`

Comment: that will not work then... you can only use RevitAPI.dll inside Revit (as a plugin)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves thanks for your comment. Do the Revit developers have deliberately done something to prevent others from using the dll in another applications by setting a security permission or something like that?

Comment: the RevitAPI.dll is actually just a thin layer to the actual implementation, not a library itself,  that's why it cannot work for standalone app, just inside Revit

Answer (score 4):

Revit API DLLs (RevitAPI.dll and RevitAPIUI.dll) were not designed to be loaded on external/standalone apps (.exe). You can only use them on Class Library (.dll) and load inside Revit as a pluging.

This happens because the API DLLs are actually a thin layer for the actual implementation. Therefore, you need Revit running to use them (as a plugin).

If you need to access Revit data from outside Revit (e.g. from an external app or export to a database), you can create a plugin, load on Revit, and from that plugin, expose the data you need. There are some events that can help, such as Idling event.

Answer (score 4):

The first error (`System.BadImageFormatException`) is because your app, compiled with AnyCPU platform, is run in x86 mode by Visual Studio. RevitAPI.dll is a x64 mixed mode assembly, so it can not be loaded in an x86 process.

The second error (`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`) is because `RevitAPI.dll` can not load its dependencies. You can solve this by setting the ouput or the working directory to the installation directory of Revit (`C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit Architecture 20xx\`). May be you can also P/Invoke `SetDllDirectory` to add this directory to the search path.

Of course, like Augusto says, Revit is not running, the majority of calls will therefore fail. But you can use simple classes like `XYZ` or `UnitUtils`.